# Enterprise iOS app distribution outside of company

Tags: ios, app-store, enterprise

If I make an app and want to sell to just one or two companies, can I legally provide them with the IPA that is signed with my developer certificate? They will then resign with their distribution certificate and distribute to their employees. I will be paid directly.

I looked here http://smartbridge.com/5-ways-to-ship-your-ios-app/ and it seems like I am not allowed to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal question, not a question about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a problem as long as each company only distributes it to their employees. It is really very similar to White Labeling. Where these companies get the app from is irrelevant and wether it has the same name or they get the app in source or ipa.

Comment: Actually, I just went over the agreement and this note stood out.  Note: This Program is for internal use, custom applications that are developed by You for Your
specific business purposes and only for use by Your employees and, in limited cases, by certain
other parties as set forth herein. If You want to distribute applications for iOS or watchOS to third
parties or obtain an application from a third party, then You must use the App Store or B2B
Program for distribution.

Comment: I do not see that you are distributing the apps to users, the companies are signing and distributing to the users. The "developed by you" certainly makes no sense as it is certainly OK to pay a developer to write an app for them either by the hour or for a fixed price.

Comment: I think this note was added recently. Apple might have banned "White Labeling". But I am not sure